How to install SDL2 and get it to work with Gforth
System is Windows 10, version 22H2, build 19045.4651
Gforth 0.7.0 installed at C:\GForth
I downloaded the https://github.com/JeremiahCheatham/Gforth-SDL2-Bindings set and installed it at
C:\GForth\sdl2
Trying to tell Gforth to use it. I must confess I couldn't even find how Gforth can display the current directory (DIR..) when I tried to check if it sees the sdl2 directory. My next step would be to check the contents of sdl2 as viewed from Gforth.
Just didn't find in the Gforth Manual how to explore the system.
Please someone help me on this... I'll see later when trying to call sdl2
Thank you very much

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
